# A paperback collection of letters between Isaac Asimov and Arthur C. Clarke

Tags: story-identification, isaac-asimov, arthur-c-clarke, authors

About 10 years ago, while browsing some Thai second-hand english bookstore, I've stumbled upon an old (70-80's, based on condition) paperback that was described as a collection of letters exchanged between Isaac Asimov and Arthur C. Clarke.

I don't recall the title, though I am almost sure that the cover was mostly dark/black.

Unfortunately, I was backpacking back then, and as my bag was already bursting at the seams. I've decided to skip it and try to find a copy back home, over the Internet.

I somehow forgot about it and the book came back to my mind few years later. But I was never able to google it out. Nothing, nada.

Anyone knows the book? Or perhaps my memory does some nasty things on me? :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Was this a work of fiction using correspondence as a device, or was it an actual record of their communications?  Do you recall any physical details of the book, like its cover?

Comment: *From Narnia to a Space Odyssey: The War of Letters Between Arthur C. Clarke and C.S. Lewis*. But i couldn't find such a thing between ACC and Asimov

Comment: *Yours, Isaac Asimov: A Lifetime of Letters* has a chapter "Clarke, de Camp and the del Reys" which includes a few letters _from_ Arthur C. Clarke, but it's probably not enough of a contribution to match the question.

Comment: Also, this relates to a real-world scenario thus it might as well be off-topic here.

Comment: @Shreedhar I think this falls into the category of "Behind-the-scenes and fandom information;" it may also match "historical context of a work."  In general questions about authors as it relates to their work is usually on-topic.

Comment: @DavidW okay. that sounds right..

Answer (score 4):

This sounded like an interesting book to read, so I did some extensive digging.  Both Asimov and Clarke were very visible and popular figures, and their careers and writings have been extensively documented.

I started with the ISFDb pages for [Isaac Asimov](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?5) and [Arthur C. Clarke](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?17).  These are extensive and apparently quite complete for their genre writings.  There is even an entry on Clarke's listing for an [untitled note of congratulations to Asimov](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1851523).  But notably there are no listings for any collaborative works.  There is also no mention of any collaboration in either's Wikipedia biography ([Asimov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov), [Clarke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_C._Clarke)) or bibliography ([Asimov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov_bibliography_(categorical)), [Clarke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_C._Clarke_bibliography)) nor in their respective entries in the SF Encyclopedia ([Asimov](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/asimov_isaac), [Clarke](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/clarke_arthur_c)).  Other resources (e.g. [Asimov Online](http://www.asimovonline.com/oldsite/asimov_catalogue.html), [worldcat](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=au%3Aarthur%20c.%20clarke&qt=advanced&dblist=638), [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/search.php?query=%28%28subject%3A%22Asimov%2C%20Isaac%22%20OR%20subject%3A%22Isaac%20Asimov%22%20OR%20title%3A%22Isaac%20Asimov%22%20OR%20description%3A%22Asimov%2C%20Isaac%22%20OR%20description%3A%22Isaac%20Asimov%22%29%20AND%20%28subject%3A%22Clarke%2C%20Arthur%20C.%22%20OR%20subject%3A%22Arthur%20C.%20Clarke%22%20OR%20title%3A%22Arthur%20C.%20Clarke%22%20OR%20description%3A%22Clarke%2C%20Arthur%20C.%22%20OR%20description%3A%22Arthur%20C.%20Clarke%22%29%29%20AND%20%28-mediatype%3Asoftware%29)) also fail to find anything.

There are 2 books listed for Clarke which *are* records of correspondence, one with [Peter Hyams](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?32011) and one with [C.S. Lewis](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?24079), so if such a book existed it should definitely appear.

I decided to approach it from the other end.  A story told as an exchange of letters/messages is called an "[epistolary novel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epistolary_novel)."  ([List entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_contemporary_epistolary_novels))  There is a [TVTropes entry](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EpistolaryNovel) for them, which lists 2 stories by Asimov ("[Blind Alley](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41602)" and "[Rejection Slips](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?108124)") but nothing by Clarke and no collaboration.

I searched a couple of online resources ([questia](https://www.questia.com/searchglobal#!/?keywords=%22Isaac%20Asimov%22%20OR%20%22Asimov,%20Isaac%22!AllWords%7C%22Arthur%20C.%20Clark%22%20OR%20%22Clarke,%20Arthur%20C.%22!AllWords&PeerReviewedType=0&pageNumber=1&mediaType=books), [worldcat](https://www.worldcat.org/search?q=kw%3Aasimov%20kw%3Aclarke%20kw%3Aletters&qt=results_page)) for books *about* both Asimov and Clarke, but again, didn't find anything that seemed relevant.

Ultimately I have only 2 very loose possibilities for matches:

[*Yours, Isaac Asimov: A Lifetime of Letters*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?102333) (1995) contains a chapter "[Clarke, de Camp and the del Reys](https://books.google.com/books?newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&id=xkRaAAAAMAAJ&dq=Yours%2C%20Isaac%20%20%20Asimov&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=clarke)" which in addition to letters from Asimov includes 3 letters from Clarke, but it isn't a story, and Clarke's letters aren't a significant contribution to the overall work.

Finally, the best I can come up with is [*Space Mail, Volume II*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?31416) (1982) which is an anthology edited by Asimov (et al.) containing stories which are all told in epistolary form.  One of these stories is "[Loophole](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41198)" by Arthur C. Clarke.  If nothing else it's in the right time period.

Comment: I agree with you. AFAIK no such book exists.

Comment: From another post here, there is "One Rejection Too Many" which has letters ostensibly by both, but not directed at each other.